# POST request to firebase functions with sim900 arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, sim900

Im trying to send POST request with sim900 connected to arduino uno.
I send it to firebase functions but I dont get it in the function.
I will be happy to get solution for my problem,
or alternative way that i can store data from sensors to firebase with sim900 or any other celular network solution).

arduino code:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial client(7,8);


String reading="{  \"testID\" : 1, }";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  client.begin(9600);
  delay(500);

  if(client.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("NotConnected");
  }
  //initSIM();
  connectGPRS();
  connectHTTP();
}

void loop()
{
}

void connectGPRS()
{ 
  client.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"www\"");//APN
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();
}

void connectHTTP()
{
  client.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"www.us-central1-**************.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld\"");//Public server IP address
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPDATA=" + String(reading.length()) + ",100000");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println(reading);
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData;

  client.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  client.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData;
}

void ShowSerialData()
{
  while(client.available()!=0)
  {
  Serial.write(client.read());
  delay(100);
  }
}
```

firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    // Check for POST request
    if (request.method !== "POST") {
        console.log('Please send a POST request');
    }
    if (request.method !== "GET") {
        console.log('Please send a GET request');
    }
    let data = request.body;
    console.log(`Hello from Firebase! ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    // console.log('testing: ' + data[0]);
    // console.log('testing: ' + data.longitude);
    // console.log('testing: ' + data['longitude']);
});
```

Thank you all!

Comment: your function is working from other device like a pc using postman?

Comment: @JorgeHernandez yes, i send post request from other site and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a definitive solution but should work on most SIM modules but make sure you have up to date firmware for SSL connection.
This is only a snip of code from my project, you can only POST, GET and DELETE using these SIM modules built in HTTP functions, there's no PUT and PATCH so a bit limited for Firebase.
This is very basic code so you may have to tweak some timing here and there. It will work a lot faster if you put code to check the responses, most delays are not necessary.

Try this command first:

```
AT+HTTPSSL=1
```

If you get an error you MUST update the module's firmware before using Firebase.

Firebase will only work with HTTPS connection.

```
// Firebase HTTPS connection, POST example

#define MODEM_TX             16
#define MODEM_RX             17

// Set serial for debug console (to Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial
// Set serial for AT commands (to SIM808 module)
#define client Serial1


void setup()
{

 SerialMon.begin(115200);

 // Set GSM module baud rate and UART pins
 client.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, MODEM_RX, MODEM_TX);
 delay(1000);


float tempIn = 21.5;
float humidity = 54.6;
float pressure = 1010.64;
char  fbtimebuff[32] = "1:30 20/2/21";

char  dataTEST[256];

char        FirebaseUrl[300];   // dimension to suit required character space
const char  FirebaseID[100]   = "https://my-project-details.firebaseio.com";    // project ID
const char  FirebaseAuth[100] = "YPXm66X-My-Big-Secrete-J9xsZsL";               // secret

strcpy(FirebaseUrl, FirebaseID);                      // Firebase account ID
strcat(FirebaseUrl, "/GPRS-Test/.json?auth=");        // Parenet/child path + .json and auth
strcat(FirebaseUrl, FirebaseAuth);
sprintf(dataTEST, "{\"TempIn\" : \"%3.2f\",\"Humidity\" : \"%2.2f\",\"Pressure\" : \"%4.2f\",\"Time\" : \"%s\"}", tempIn, humidity, pressure, fbtimebuff);


// connect to GPRS network

  SerialMon.printf("\n\nConnect to GPRS\n");
  client.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(500);
  client.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);

// post to Firebase

  SerialMon.printf("post function to Firebase\n");
  client.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+HTTPSSL=1");    // set SSL for HTTPS
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\"," + String(FirebaseUrl));
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);  client.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  int stlen = strlen(dataTEST);
  SerialMon.printf("length: %d\n", stlen);
  client.println("AT+HTTPDATA=" + String(stlen) + ",100000");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  SerialMon.printf("set data\n");
  client.println(dataTEST);
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  SerialMon.printf("POST data to Firebase\n");
  client.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(6000);
  client.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  SerialMon.printf("Dissconect\n");
  client.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);

// now disconnect from GPRS network

  client.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);
  client.println("AT+CGATT=0");
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(1000);

}

void loop()
{

}
```